# Write Dictionary<string, dynamic> to JSON file

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

If I have a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` where the keys use dot notation, is there an easy way to convert to JSON with JSON.NET? For example:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> records = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
    { "Name.First", "John" },
    { "Name.Last", "Doe" },
    { "ContactInfo", new ContactInfo {
        Phone = "555-555-5555",
        Foo = 999,
        Bar = true
    } }
};
```

Desired JSON would be:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "John",
        "last": "Doe"
    },
    "contactInfo": {
        "phone": "555-555-5555",
        "foo": 999,
        "bar": true
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems suspect you are storing this sort of information in a dictionary (in this particular way). Also every time you think about using the `dynamic` type, tell yourself there is always 
likely a better way

Comment: You can use custom `JsonConverter` to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are many ways to do this. However, the main problem is the design choice of the *dictionary* with `dynamic` values, without further explanation this seems very suspect.

However, assuming you know best. You would have to project your data to another form, or write some sort of converter one way or the other. I chose an *anonymous type*, since your data is relatively simple.

```
var temp = new
{
   name = new
   {
      first = records["Name.First"],
      last = records["Name.Last"],
   },
   ContactInfo = records["ContactInfo"]
};

// this is just one way to get your `ContactInfo` camel case, there are others
var contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
   NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
   ContractResolver = contractResolver,
   Formatting = Formatting.Indented
});


Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe"
  },
  "contactInfo": {
    "phone": "555-555-5555",
    "foo": 999,
    "bar": true
  }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This answer is not optimal, I would consider revaluating your choices of data structure*</sub>

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it made me rethink the problem. As you suggested, working with a different data structure using JObjects & JArrays got me to where I needed to be. Good advice!

Answer (score -1):

Use the JsonSerializer. You first need to import it

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then use the following code to get the JSON string

```
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
```

Comment: This is not going to produce the desired outcome